# How to change an object attribute in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I want to change a boolean attribute of an object in JavaScript (the object is from a library called fullPage.js). I want to change the navigation attribute to false, preferably from another file.

[image: this is the object]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you written the code by yourself, or is it hardcoded to the library?

Comment: Please post some code to show what you have tried

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You cannot change the object unless you extract it from the code you show.
So `const parms = { autoscrolling:true, navigation: false,....}; new fullpage('#fullpage',parms)`

Comment: Explain your use case in more detail and what higher level problem you are trying to solve. You may need to use the fullpage API

Answer (score -1):

pretty straight forward.  after you create the object just change the value for the key.  If you want to do it from a file you have several ways of doing this.

1. place the object first in local storage
2. store the object on your backend
3. place the object as a data element in your html

Show us what you've done so far

```js
let fullpage = {autoscrolling:true,
                navagation:true}
            
console.log(fullpage)

fullpage.navagation = false

console.log(fullpage)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm new here so sorry for the imprecisions of my question